# Makefile no longer works (Windows)

Tags: windows, makefile

I created this makefile almost two years ago in Windows 7:

```
SRC_DIRS = ./src/oasis ./src/oasis/commands/basic ./src/oasis/commands/immortal ./src/oasis/commands/socials ./src/oasis/util
COMPILE_FLAGS = -d ./classes
DOC_FLAGS = -quiet -private -d ./doc -sourcepath ./src -subpackages oasis -linkoffline http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api .

all:
    @echo Compiling source code...
    @javac $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(dir)/*.java)
    @echo Creating javadocs...
    @javadoc $(DOC_FLAGS)
    @echo Done.

class:
    @echo Compiling source code...
    @javac $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(dir)/*.java)
    @echo Done.

docs:
    @echo Creating javadocs...
    @javadoc $(DOC_FLAGS)
    @echo Done.

clean:
    @echo Removing classes...
    @rmdir classes /q /s
    @mkdir classes
    @echo Removing javadocs...
    @rmdir doc /q /s
    @mkdir doc
    @echo Done.
```

I used to navigate to its folder with cmd.exe, and then type "make all" or "make class" or whatever... and it would work! Now I'm returning to this project almost 2 years later, on a new computer (also Windows 7) and the "make" command isn't recognized. I don't remember installing any special software to use makefiles in Windows. Why won't it work anymore?

Comment: It looks like make is not installed. Just type `make` and see what does it say?

Comment: @dbasic it says, "'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: That makefile looks like it's written for GNU `make`.  You'll need to get a Win32 version of it or maybe install Cygwin. Try one from UnxUtils, GnuWin32, or a MinGW distribution (I like nuwen's distro). Be aware that some MinGW distributions will name the GNU make utility `mingw32-make.exe` to avoid conflicts (just rename or copy it to `make.exe` if you want).

Comment: It simple means make is not installed. Michael Burr mentions how to install it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thank you! I downloaded nuwen's distro and it installed so easily, works superbly. Makefile is working once again. If you post that as an answer to my question I'll mark it as correct. :)